# Is Microsoft / Google embracing jQuery a good thing?

Tags: jquery

I love that Microsoft and Google are embracing jQuery but is this good? How can I deal with the possible problems when I code?

### The embracing of jQuery

Is it good or bad that the likes of Microsoft and Google are embracing jQuery?

In the case Microsoft & Google they are both providing free hosting on their CDNs (awesome) and in the case of Microsoft they are submitting features (maybe cool?)

### Upside or Downside

However think about this ... by packaging jQuery with Visual Studio (for example) very quickly you might end up with sites relying on rather OLD versions of the library ...

**In my case I've already run into clients running 1.3 code, when my work relied on 1.4's much improved features. Yet these clients don't have the resources to update their *old* code ...**

This has long been a marginal drawback of JAVA and .Net ... but mostly jQuery has avoided this ...

### The Question

Will the community benefit from this "embrace" or be hurt, and stuck with old versions?

What do you think?

Comment: Maybe ... not really aware of the protocal. But I'm interested in  "answers" to this, and also ... suggestions on how to handle the problem of clients using "old" versions of the library.

Comment: As it's a discussion topic, it will probably be closed. Read the FAQ for more info. CW might improve your chances of it staying open, but SO isn't really the right place for discussions.

Comment: @Andy E ... Since you have way more reputation then me and reference Futurama with your avatar I have to give you some credence ... but I am very interested in *answers* ... not so much discussion. If "Programming in Linux vs. Windows" can be hot topic on SO ... why not this?

Comment: @Justin: well, unless a diamond moderator decides to close it, it's mostly left up to the community.  So it's not like there's no chance of it staying open.  The community can vote to close it and even if it's closed it can be reopened again.  The FAQ states, *"Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion"*.  Questions requiring extended discussion might be more suited to the upcoming *chat.stackoverflow.com*.

Comment: @Andy E: Thanks for the clarification. I think I should have worded my question better in the first place ... but I'll just let it stand and see what happens.

Comment: @Andy E: Never mind, I decided to slightly edit my question ... hopefully it will illicit the responses I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm totally honest, I'm not keen on jQuery getting too cosy with Microsoft. For one, the improvements that Microsoft have been suggesting are [somewhat bloated](http://github.com/nje/jquery-tmpl/blob/master/jquery.tmpl.js) and IMO should not be added to the jQuery core. Some of them are simply unnecessary and go against quite a few JS best practices: E.g. their [datalink solution](http://github.com/nje/jquery-datalink), which they want added to the jQuery core, is both bloated, badly implemented and not addressing the needs of 99% of jQuery developers.

I'm happy that developers at MS are embracing jQuery but I don't see why they need to add all this crazy stuff to the core. Are they not satisfied with anything less than permanent inclusion in the core? How about a simple plugin?

Comment: Good points. 

Based on what I heard at the SF jQuery Conf I do think the jQuery team hopes to address this by making specific "core plugins" that aren't included in the true core, but are tested/proven to work with the core.

I believe they intend some of the Microsoft stuff to be included only as these "core plugins" ...

Still it is a scary thought.

Comment: Well, I guess if they're not actually intending it to go in the core then it's okay. But still, that data-link thing is just wild! Microsoft seem totally out of touch with most of people that develop with jQuery.

Comment: Yes, honestly ... I went to the session by MS at the SF jQuery Conf, with MS showing off the data-link stuff ... and more then one person asked "why would I want this???" I can see some value ... but I agree it's an odd rabbit trail to follow. If we are lucky Open Source will show it's true value tho and sort things out?

Comment: @Justin - It's been said many times by both sides that the code they're talking about won't be **in jQuery Core**, this is a key distinction.  A plugin isn't library bloat, it's completely optional.  All approval for core additions is done completely by the jQuery team, not Microsoft.  "Why would I want this?"...well, they're not saying you would, but if you *do*, you can just go grab the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Upside

-It makes jquery a corporate thing; What I'm trying to say is that, when I develop using jQuery as my preferred ajax library I don't get bothered for not being used/developed in corporate environment.

Comment: And what happens when that 'corporate environment' is already a major version behind? Thoughts?

Comment: It's still much more easier to support jquery than microsoft ajax toolkit. From my point of view and experience.

Answer (score 0):

Sites relying on old versions are better than nothing. If not jQuery, they might rely something unused or undocumented. Would you rather have the ability to develop for Flash Player 8 or Silverlight 1?

Comment: I guess my point is ... say the client included a script tag including a old version of jQuery in their site template. That's not a big problem with Flash or Silverlight ... but a big problem with jQuery!